# Python Fattening Complex JSON

Tags: python, json, nested, normalize

I have a LinkedIn dataset of follower statistics in the following JSON (Removed many key pair values for easy understanding). In this, each key has a different number of inner key pair values.

Can somebody help convert this to a CSV output using python?

```
{
    "paging": { "start": 0, "count": 10, "links": [] },
    "elements": [
        {
            "followerCountsByAssociationType": [
                {
                    "followerCounts": {
                        "organicFollowerCount": 2775,
                        "paidFollowerCount": 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "followerCounts": {
                        "organicFollowerCount": 13,
                        "paidFollowerCount": 0
                    },
                    "associationType": "EMPLOYEE"
                }
            ],
            "followerCountsByRegion": [
                {
                    "region": "urn:li:region:7312",
                    "followerCounts": {
                        "organicFollowerCount": 2,
                        "paidFollowerCount": 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "region": "urn:li:region:6981",
                    "followerCounts": {
                        "organicFollowerCount": 2,
                        "paidFollowerCount": 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    "region": "urn:li:region:620",
                    "followerCounts": {
                        "organicFollowerCount": 2,
                        "paidFollowerCount": 0
                    }
                }
            ],
            "followerCountsBySeniority": [
                {
                    "followerCounts": {
                        "organicFollowerCount": 12,
                        "paidFollowerCount": 0
                    },
                    "seniority": "urn:li:seniority:8"
                },
                {
                    "followerCounts": {
                        "organicFollowerCount": 5,
                        "paidFollowerCount": 0
                    },
                    "seniority": "urn:li:seniority:9"
                },
                {
                    "followerCounts": {
                        "organicFollowerCount": 2,
                        "paidFollowerCount": 0
                    },
                    "seniority": "urn:li:seniority:1"
                }
            ],
            "followerCountsByIndustry": [
                {
                    "followerCounts": {
                        "organicFollowerCount": 1,
                        "paidFollowerCount": 0
                    },
                    "industry": "urn:li:industry:51"
                },
                {
                    "followerCounts": {
                        "organicFollowerCount": 1,
                        "paidFollowerCount": 0
                    },
                    "industry": "urn:li:industry:74"
                },
                {
                    "followerCounts": {
                        "organicFollowerCount": 1,
                        "paidFollowerCount": 0
                    },
                    "industry": "urn:li:industry:77"
                },
                {
                    "followerCounts": {
                        "organicFollowerCount": 1,
                        "paidFollowerCount": 0
                    },
                    "industry": "urn:li:industry:78"
                },
            ],
            "followerCountsByFunction": [
                {
                    "followerCounts": {
                        "organicFollowerCount": 3,
                        "paidFollowerCount": 0
                    },
                    "function": "urn:li:function:14"
                },
                {
                    "followerCounts": {
                        "organicFollowerCount": 3,
                        "paidFollowerCount": 0
                    },
                    "function": "urn:li:function:21"
                },
                {
                    "followerCounts": {
                        "organicFollowerCount": 2,
                        "paidFollowerCount": 0
                    },
                    "function": "urn:li:function:11"
                },
                {
                    "followerCounts": {
                        "organicFollowerCount": 2,
                        "paidFollowerCount": 0
                    },
                    "function": "urn:li:function:17"
                },
                {
                    "followerCounts": {
                        "organicFollowerCount": 2,
                        "paidFollowerCount": 0
                    },
                    "function": "urn:li:function:1"
                },
            ],
            "followerCountsByStaffCountRange": [
                {
                    "followerCounts": {
                        "organicFollowerCount": 267,
                        "paidFollowerCount": 0
                    },
                    "staffCountRange": "SIZE_1001_TO_5000"
                },
                {
                    "followerCounts": {
                        "organicFollowerCount": 185,
                        "paidFollowerCount": 0
                    },
                    "staffCountRange": "SIZE_201_TO_500"
                },
                {
                    "followerCounts": {
                        "organicFollowerCount": 131,
                        "paidFollowerCount": 0
                    },
                    "staffCountRange": "SIZE_501_TO_1000"
                },
                {
                    "followerCounts": {
                        "organicFollowerCount": 81,
                        "paidFollowerCount": 0
                    },
                    "staffCountRange": "SIZE_5001_TO_10000"
                },
                {
                    "followerCounts": {
                        "organicFollowerCount": 74,
                        "paidFollowerCount": 0
                    },
                    "staffCountRange": "SIZE_2_TO_10"
                },
                {
                    "followerCounts": {
                        "organicFollowerCount": 10,
                        "paidFollowerCount": 0
                    },
                    "staffCountRange": "SIZE_1"
                }
            ],
            "followerCountsByCountry": [
                {
                    "followerCounts": {
                        "organicFollowerCount": 1,
                        "paidFollowerCount": 0
                    },
                    "country": "urn:li:country:es"
                },
                {
                    "followerCounts": {
                        "organicFollowerCount": 1,
                        "paidFollowerCount": 0
                    },
                    "country": "urn:li:country:ph"
                },
                {
                    "followerCounts": {
                        "organicFollowerCount": 1,
                        "paidFollowerCount": 0
                    },
                    "country": "urn:li:country:ng"
                }
            ],
            "organizationalEntity": "urn:li:organization:28849398"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried using the `json_normalize(data['Elements'])` but that gives the following [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Swey6.png)
I am sure that there must be some parameter in `json_normalize()` that can simplify the inner nesting.

The desired output is as follows-

| FollwerCounByAssociationorganicfollowecount | FollwerCounByAssociationpaidfollowecount | AssociationType | Region | RegionOrganicFollowercount | RegionpaidFollowercount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2775 | 0 | Employee | urn:li:region:7312 | 2 | 0 |
|  |  |  | urn:li:region:6981 | 2 | 0 |

.......And so on

Now I have only made a small part of the output but largely for as many entries in the last the columns will go on (while for the others it will be `null`)

Would appreciate any help possible! Thanks!

Comment: There are many, many ways this data could be stored in a CSV file. Which particular layout did you have in mind?

Comment: Include, in the question itself, the output you expect for the given input. (While you are at it, your sample input doesn't need to be so large.)

Comment: Did you mean "Flattening" in the question title rather than "Fattening"?

Comment: Hey @chepner, I have added the desired output (sample-due to too many columns) in the question itself. Do let me know how this can be done, thanks :)

Comment: Why are you trying to create a table in the question? CSV is just text with commas as field delimiters. You seem to be trying to recreate visual formatting of a table *built* from a CSV file.